# Schur-Weyl duality and Ring of representations

Tags: algebraic-geometry, representation-theory, lie-groups, algebraic-groups

The ring of representations of the symmetric group is isomorphic to the ring of symmetric functions. The Schur-Weyl duality relates the irreducible representations of the symmetric group and that of the general linear group. Using the Schur-Weyl duality, is there way to find the ring of representations of the general linear group in terms of the symmetric functions ?